# PostgreSqlTestcontainer is missing / unable to locate it, in my NET7 application

Tags: c#, .net, postgresql, testcontainers

I'm trying to use [Testcontainers (for .NET)](https://dotnet.testcontainers.org/) in a .NET "XUnit" class library project.

When I add the nuget, the file says it cannot find the actual `PostgreSqlTestcontainer`:

[image]

given the following `.csproj` data:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>

    <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>
    <IsTestProject>true</IsTestProject>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="17.3.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Testcontainers" Version="3.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="xunit" Version="2.4.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="xunit.runner.visualstudio" Version="2.4.5">
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="coverlet.collector" Version="3.1.2">
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
    </PackageReference>
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

And the for the life of me, I can't figure out where this class resides.

Can anyone help, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting from Version 3.0.0, specific containers moved into their own packages

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Testcontainers.PostgreSql

They also changed the name to PostgreSqlContainer

Comment: Awesome! They look like [they call their containers "Modules"](https://dotnet.testcontainers.org/modules/) when I would have just called them "Containers". And [they have a modern example of PostgreSQL](https://dotnet.testcontainers.org/modules/postgres/) ! cheers mate!